# Why is this Highcharts xAxis actual max greater than the xAxis.max I have set?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is a Highcharts chart with a spline series. The xAxis max is set to 9405, as shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bridgeland/253gq/1/

[image: X axis max is 9405, as intended]

When I add a column series, and align it with the spline using pointRange and pointInterval, the actual max of the X axis seems to be increased to about 11000, as you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bridgeland/5nq4q/

[image: Effective X axis max of about 11000]

There is no data above 8620 in the first series, and no data above 8360 in the second series. So why is HighCharts increasing the effective max of the X axis? And how can I control this?

(You may be wondering why I care so much what the real maximum is. It would not be a big problem if I had only a single spline and a single column series to align. But in the actual application, I have a second spline with a different xAxis and a different scale, and I need to align the scales of the two splines. I am doing this by setting the max of each xAxis, but my alignment is way off when Highcharts overrides the max I set.)

The code corresponding to the second fiddle, the one that shows the problem:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            alignTicks: false
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 1 
        },
        xAxis: {
            min: 0, 
            max: 9405
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'spline',
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            zIndex: 1,
            data: [
                [0, 1],
                [215.5115677836167, 1],
                // much data omitted
                [8620.462711344668, 0]
            ]
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            pointPadding: 0.01,
            groupPadding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0,
            shadow: false,
            pointPlacement: 'between',
            zIndex: 0,
            minPointLength: 3, 
            data: [1, 0.8303045243052317, 0.507000086078798, 0.3012666720025181, 0.15608877940134103, 0.07002459966684138, 0.04309138172365523, 0.014811084204643832],
            pointRange: 1045,
            pointInterval: 1045
        }]
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help on this. As a friend of mine says, stackoverflow is the single most useful site on the internets. And it is not the site, really, it's you.

Comment: It looks an awful lot like it might be making the max 10x1045 instead of 9x1045. Removing `pointRange` and `pointInterval` fixes it, but that's of course not the chart you want. Oddly, decreasing those values doesn't seem to cause the problem to disappear in the way it should if it were as simple as (internally) taking 10*pointRange and making that the max if greater than the current max. Sorry I don't have more info/help than that...

Comment: Perhaps so, but it does not seem consistent. For example, changing the max to 9000 makes the true max somewhere between 9x1045 and 10x1045.

Answer (score 0):

It is related with fact, that highcharts need to calculate ticks positions, regular. So I advice to modify tickInterval or use tickPositions/tickPostioner.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Comment: adding tickInterval or tickPositioner has no effect on the calculated max. For example, this fiddle shows the effect of adding a tickPositioner function: http://jsfiddle.net/Bridgeland/5nq4q/2/ The ticks are changed but the max remains the same. (Or perhaps I don't understand your suggestion?)

Comment: You have point in 8620, max is 9405, so when you set ticks in 0 and 8000, so you assume that chart will be cutted in 8000?

Comment: I expected the max to be 9405. But in fact the X axis goes well to the right of 9405, to roughly 11000.

Comment: Not. I need to be able to set the max xAxis precisely. (In the actual application I have 2 splines on 2 different X axes. I need to align their scales. I wanted to do that alignment by setting the max of each X axis. But somehow Highcharts is overriding the value I am setting, e.g. I set 9405 but Highcharts decides it should actually be 11000.)

Comment: Indeed it looks like problem with columns, which I reported here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2028 Because with spline series http://jsfiddle.net/5nq4q/4/ works properly